# Mageplaza navigation layer.js not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, layered-navigation, mageplaza

Mageplaza layer navigation js updated from

> app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/web/js/view/layer.js

this location but it is not updated.
but on console js event is showing on below location.

https://staging.ihouzit.com/pub/static/version1574138983/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/view/layer.min.js

please help in this/..

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your file **layer.js**

I will Explain why this Happen because you have enable the minify of JS.

Once you have enable the Minify JS. your JS file create min file then this name converts in **.min.js** & minify file creates in pub/static Path then now:

```
Your file path: app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/web/js/view/layer.js

saved by Magento Path: /pub/static/version1574138983/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/view/layer.min.js
```

Command to Execute after Changes are:

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f && chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Hope you understand!!